# How do I get the properties and destination values of a running Jquery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Given an element `$MyElement` that is actively being animated, how can I determine the properties affected by the animation, and their final destination, without interfering with the running animation?

Example:

```
$MyElement.css('height','200px').slideDown(2000);
$MyElement.GetAnimationProperties(); // would return `{'height':'200px'}`
```

Obviously, the call to `GetAnimationProperties()` would be in a different scope than the code that starts the animation (Mutation Observer). This would allow a second *autonomous* plugin that needs to know the final animation property value (like height) to work properly, without interfering with the original plug-in.

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/queue/ but I don't know if it will help you.

Comment: I tried printing `.queue()` in the callback, but it was just an empty array.